# Iterate blocks of struct in memory using pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Good day,

I am trying to create dynamic list of struct using malloc function. For each block of struct, i want to set the struct fields and then i would like to loop through each memory. Below is the code that i wrote :-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int portnum;
    int baudrate;
} port_t;

int main()
{

    port_t *port_pt = (port_t *)malloc(sizeof(port_t) * 2); //allocate two blocks

    port_pt->id = 1;
    port_pt->portnum = 9;
    port_pt->baudrate = 4800;

    printf("id : %i, port :COM%i baud : %i\n\n", port_pt->id, port_pt->portnum, port_pt->baudrate);

    port_pt++; //try make pointer point to next block
    port_pt->id = 2;
    port_pt->portnum = 9;
    port_pt->baudrate = 4800;
    port_pt--; //try to make pointer point to prev block

    int count = 0;
    while (port_pt != NULL)
    {
        printf("DEBUG id : %i, port :COM%i baud : %i\n", port_pt->id, port_pt->portnum, port_pt->baudrate);
        port_pt++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, when i compile and run this code. I get this lines output instead of two lines only : -

[image: debug output]

Can anyone show me where i did wrong? I am really struggling with pointers.

Comment: `while (port_pt != NULL)`why would this test ever com true?

Comment: How can a pointer become `NULL` by incrementing it? That should be a lot of iterations.

Comment: You don't need to increment and decrement `port_pt`. You can use it like an array, e.g. `for (int i=0; i<2; i++) printf("%d\n", port_pt[i].id);`  In fact, you *shouldn't* change `port_pt` because you need the original pointer to `free` the memory.

Comment: @mch i think i had the wrong concept that incrementing pointer will cause it to point to NULL after two blocks. Then what should i do to iterate the memory blocks?

Comment: @user3386109 I got it. Thank you

Comment: @HarithIkhwan make sure to free() the pointer, to prevent memory leaks, as malloc does NOT have automatic garbage collection

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
    while (port_pt != NULL)
    {
        printf("DEBUG id : %i, port :COM%i baud : %i\n", port_pt->id, port_pt->portnum, port_pt->baudrate);
        port_pt++;
    }
```

change this to

```
int count;
   for(count=0;count<2;count++)
   {
        printf("DEBUG id : %i, port :COM%i baud : %i\n", port_pt->id, port_pt->portnum, port_pt->baudrate);
        port_pt++;
   }
```

Because, By incrementing port_pt did not comes to NULL and don't forget to free() the memory allocated by malloc()

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is an array (with incorrect usage as mentioned by Sri), not a linked list.

To create a linked list, you need to add a pointer to your struct to your struct (<- not a grammar error!), but as your code currently is, that is not possible. You have to change the declaration as well:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int portnum;
    int baudrate;
} port_t;
```

to:

```
typedef struct port_t
{
    struct port_t *next;
    int id;
    int portnum;
    int baudrate;
} port_t;
```

`struct tag` puts `tag` into a special namespace that is immediately (before even the opening `{`), and this namespace is accessible only via `struct` (in C. C++ puts `tag` into the parent namespace as well, so the above *will* give a redeclaration error, thus why modern headers tend to use `typedef struct tag_s {...} tag_t;`).

From there, you would allocate single element blocks using malloc, assigning each new block pointer to the `next` field in the previous block, and set the final `next` field to `NULL` (or 0). Of course, you will want to keep track of the first block, and you will need to free each block individually too.